# Redirect Request using SpringMVC

Tags: spring-mvc

i want to redirect to another request with the same http method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "first", method = RequestMethod.GET/POST/PUT/DELETE)
public String first(){
    return "redirect:second";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "second", method = RequestMethod.GET/POST/PUT/DELETE)
public String second(){
    // do something
}
```

but i found all redirect request with GET method, is there any solution?

Comment: No, there isn't. A redirect can only do a GET.

Comment: Are there other ways to implement POST to another POST

Comment: Yes. Don't do a redirect. Just call the same method third() from first() and second(). Why would you need a redirect in this case?

Comment: to pretend url, but i will request another controller. Calls the method can directly?